# jfxrt.jar not in JDK 1.8?

Tags: java, linux, javafx

I just updated my JDK to the JDK 1.8 because i couldnt find the jfxrt.jar needed by java FX in the 1.7 version.

I downloaded the JDK from here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Specifically the version:
jdk-8u5-linux-i586.rpm

I use opensuse 13.1 by the way.

Now after the installation my usr/java/jdk1.9_05/lib still does not contain the jfxrt.jar.

Has anybody an idea why, I read that this version should actually contain it. Can I fix this problem putting the jar in ther manually?

Comment: I have the same issue with UBUNTU 15.10 with oracle jdk8.74, netbeans unable to compile javafx projects. If you somehow managed to get it working please share with the rest of us

Comment: For reference, I, too, had this problem. I was able to solve it by copying the `jfxrt.jar` file from another Java 8 download into the `jre/lib/ext` directory manually, as you proposed. Oddly enough, a version of Java 8 that I had on my system from several months ago had this jar file located there, but my current Java 8 installation did not. I cannot explain this difference.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For me on OSX it's under `jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar`. I'd guess it's in an analogous place on your machine. Try `/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_05/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar`

Comment: I just found the jar in C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_300\lib\ext and added to the project classpath, even though i have added the same jre to classpath already. Then it worked

Answer (score 1):

Am using linuxmint 18.1 and i had the same issue. i realized that the open jdk i had didn't have the jfxrt.jar library.
Download another jdk from oracle and then install it. Remember to change the path in the netbeans.conf file in the netbeans installation folder.

Answer (score 1):

From the above comments, i tried this.

I added jfxrt.jar(Downloaded JDK) to PC. 
In eclipse, right click project --> properties --> Libraries --> Add external jar and choose the jar file.

The error went away.

Answer (score -2):

You have to add `requires jfxrt;` to your module-info if you have trouble after adding jfxrt.jar

Comment: Adding more explanation to your answer improves the answer quality!!

Comment: Java 1.8 does not use modules.