# JavaFx Does not Build or Run

Tags: java, javafx

I have been trying to start a summer project using JavaFX (Using Intellij on windows). First, I got an error that said that the SDK was not properly defined (which it was) and it couldn't recognize any JavaFX classes. Now I have gotten it to show me a different error by adding Global Libraries from the java 11.0.2 lib folder. Now it recognizes the classes through my Global Libraries but gives me a different error. I pasted the entire error message bellow. Not sure what's wrong now BUT it might be causing it because I added my global libraries from a different folder than my SDK is in.

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
```

Comment: This is only the first 7 lines of the error.

Comment: are you sure your JDK has JavaFX? It's not included by default, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27178895/cannot-resolve-symbol-javafx-application-in-intellij-idea-ide

Comment: Yes it should, idk how to check that though... Do you have a link to a JDK that includes JavaFX by default?

Comment: For some help setting up JavaFX 11+ see [Getting Started with JavaFX](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/)—specifically the IntelliJ section. Regarding your `InvocationTargetException`, you need to show the entire [stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors). Such an exception is never the root cause of the problem.

Comment: @raaamonnn try this one https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu/zulufx/