# Intellij and openjdk 8 with javafx-fxml.jar not working properly in linux mint

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, fxml

I am having trouble with **IntelliJ** and **openjdk 8**, I have to work on a project that requires me to use **jdk 8**, I followed the instructions from the second answer from this thread, [cannot resolve symbol javafx.application in IntelliJ Idea IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27178895/cannot-resolve-symbol-javafx-application-in-intellij-idea-ide). All the jar files work properly but there seems to be a problem with `fxml.jar`, when I try to run or build the file I get this error message :

```
Error:(8, 19) java: cannot access javafx.fxml.Initializable
  bad class file: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/javafx-fxml.jar!/javafx/fxml/Initializable.class
    class file has wrong version 54.0, should be 52.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

I have searched online for a previous version of the class file but I didn't find anything, what can I do to make it run? I run **Linux Mint 19.02 Tina** on my laptop, all of my colleagues use windows on their computers and we all use IntelliJ, they do not have any problems, everything runs like a charm.

Comment: It looks like `sudo apt-get install openjfx` installs JavaFX for Java 10 which will not work with Java 8. There is an open issue to provide openjfx for OpenJDK 8: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-build/issues/577.

Comment: Try this workaround https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-build/issues/577#issuecomment-518819515 It should solve your problem until the github issue is not fixed.